# xe:dropDownButton not working in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, xpages

Below is an XPage that works fine in both FireFox and Chrome, but does not populate the dropdown in IE. ssAppMenu.get is a sessipnScope JAVA Bean that returns a vector of valid entries for the dropdown. I have called it in the beforepageload and stored it is the viewScope.vsTestAppMenu to make sure it is returning the correct values, and it is. So the Bean woud appear to be doing it's job. When the button first displays it displays "-- Select An Application --" because ssApplication is null so that part works, but computing the tree node does not. I'm using IE 8.0.

My client is going to have to upgrade their IE to 11. It works in 11.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex" style="margin-left:50.0px">
    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:script src="/js Utils.jss" clientSide="false"></xp:script>
        <xp:styleSheet href="/approval.css"></xp:styleSheet>
    </xp:this.resources>


    <xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.vsTestAppMenu = ssAppMenu.get();
sessionScope.ssApplication = "CIP Access"}]]></xp:this.beforePageLoad>


    <xp:br></xp:br>

<xe:dropDownButton id="selectApp">
    <xe:this.treeNodes>
        <xe:basicContainerNode>
            <xe:this.label>
                <![CDATA[#{javascript:var s:String =sessionScope.ssApplication;
(s == null || s == "")? "-- Select An Application --" : s;}]]>
            </xe:this.label>
            <xe:this.children>
            <!-- ssAppMenu is a session Scope Bean that returns a list of
            valid menu items    -->
                <xe:repeatTreeNode
                    var="thisApp" indexVar="index" loaded="true"
                    value="#{javascript:ssAppMenu.get()}">
                    <xe:this.children>
                        <xe:basicLeafNode   label="#{javascript:thisApp}"
                            submitValue="#{javascript:thisApp}">
                        </xe:basicLeafNode>
                        <xe:separatorTreeNode loaded="true" />
                    </xe:this.children>
                </xe:repeatTreeNode>                                           </xe:this.children>
        </xe:basicContainerNode>
    </xe:this.treeNodes>
<!--eventHandler removed for clarity -->
</xe:dropDownButton>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: IE8!? Really? Urgh 

Comment: That is what my client was running, got them to upgrade and now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was an issue with my client using a very old copy of IE. I seldom use IE so I assumed it was my code -- it wasn't.